# Upgraded to aws-sdk v3 but still getting v2 maintenance mode warning message

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

Ive upgraded my application to use aws sdk v3 for the ssm service by following the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ssm/

`const { SSMClient, GetParametersCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-ssm");`

but continue to get the error message:

`NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.`

on the ssm.send command.

```
        const params = new GetParametersCommand({
          Names: name,
          WithDecryption: true,
        });

        const result = await ssm.send(params);
```

What have i missed?

The version in my package.json is `"@aws-sdk/client-ssm": "^3.327.0",`

Comment: as a workaround, you may suppress the warning by adding environment variable AWS_SDK_JS_SUPPRESS_MAINTENANCE_MODE_MESSAGE=1

Comment: If you are using Serverless, have you upgraded to Serverless 3 too?  I have read elsewhere that it will likely get ride of the message if you have done everything else, but I personally have not actually tried it yet.